# Cannot Insert details to my site with INERT Query (using MySqli)

Tags: php

I'm trying to install php code inside html file that will present all the club friends by using SELECT query for MySQL.
can't see the results inside the page.
need help.
Here's the entire php code the integrated inside html:

```
   <?php
//Input posted data.
$Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
$Lname = $_POST["Lname"];
$Mail = $_POST["Mail"];
$row = $_POST["row"];

  // Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root',"");

 //Check if the connection was opened, if not prompt the error to the page.
if (!$conn)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

//Select the data base.
mysqli_select_db($conn, "Club");

//Set the character set to utf-8 to allow hebrew.
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");    

//SQL query - user Details 
$sql = "SELECT Fname, Lname, Mail FROM customers";

//Run SQL query
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die (mysqli_connect_errno());

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Fname: " . $row["Fname"]. " - Name: " . $row["Lname"]. " " . $row
["Mail"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}   


 //Close the SQL connection.
mysqli_close($conn);

 ?>
```

Thanks in Advance,
JasonB.

Comment: `$results` != `$result`.

Comment: Is the PHP in the source of your HTML?

Comment: `mysqli_connect()` *expects* a database name be passed to it, not selected afterwards.

Comment: @JayBlanchard It's weird how the docs present this: `mysqli_connect` an alias for `mysqli::__construct()`. In there, we see _dbname
If provided will specify the default database to be used when performing queries._ But if we go to `select_db` page, the examples pass the database, 'implying' it's obligatory. hmm Edit: it does provide a weird note: _This function should only be used to change the default database for the connection. [...]_

Comment: Yep - it's that weird note I normally point out @FirstOne and if you think about it for a second - what is the *default* database for MySQL?

Comment: If it wasn't for the **If provided [...]** in `dbname` parameter. I was thinking in those cases where you want your code to create the database, so you just connect without actually selecting one. Besides, the parameter is there, it won't hurt to use it, right? It even seems like less work xD @JayBlanchard

Comment: It's why I use PDO @FirstOne

Comment: @JayBlanchard same!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "s" from the $result variable. This line:

```
$results = mysqli_query($conn,...
```

have to become:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,...
```

In your code you assign some $_POST data to a few unused variables. This is used typically when you want to filter the data from your database. When you want to add "WHERE" clause for example. And if you want to use the $_POST data, you should sanitize it.

You can also add this right after the opening **php** tag:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Add this only in development environment or just to see if there are any errors and remove it after the errors are fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys. I've removed the extra "s" from results (some how I didn't see it...), I used Atanas code for checking any errors but there was nothing. still, can't see the details for the database. any ideas?...

Comment: Are you sure that there are records in your database? You can try to make another file "somename.php" with the following content:  

<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root',"", "customers");
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO customers (Fname,Lname,Mail)
VALUES ('Test','Family','user@example.com')");
mysqli_close($conn);

Run this file from your browser and than try your code again.

Comment: I already have a php file with INSERT query and it works great. just cannot deal with the SELECT query. I've tried some code that were suggested on net but no results...

Comment: How can I send you the whole code? If I want to do it here on the forum i'll have to open a new Q...

Comment: at the end of your code place 
var_dump($result->num_rows);
to see what's inside. Here is something that may help you:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp